# Where are my screencast keys?

Tags: interface, shortcut

I can't find the *Screencast Keys* which allow me to start the display. I have tried the right hand pop-up menu using the hotkey <kbd>N</kbd>, but I could not find the *Screencast Keys* menu which is usually located under the *Transform orientations* rollout.

Comment: Screencast keys is an addon, which you first have to download install and enable.

Comment: Currently, it has beeen removed from trunk. see [here](http://www.blendernation.com/2014/07/02/screencast-keys-addon-is-removed-b3d/) You have to download it and install manually.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

[Screencast keys](https://github.com/nutti/Screencast-Keys/) is now an external addon (it was formerly distributed with blender, but [has since been removed](http://www.blendernation.com/2014/07/02/screencast-keys-addon-is-removed-b3d/#comment-638590)). To use it:

1. [download it](https://github.com/nutti/Screencast-Keys/releases/latest) and then click *install from file* in <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>,</kbd>*> User preferences > Addons*, then navigate to where you downloaded the zip and install.
2. Enable it, then turn it on in *3D view > Properties region (*<kbd>N</kbd>*) > Screen cast keys*:

[image]

Comment: Alternatively try: http://jeh3.net/screencast-keys-status-addon-rewrite