# How do I display what keys I use?

Tags: interface, add-on

Basically, what I'm saying is, I've been watching a Blender YouTube tutorial (or something like that), I saw that a lot of users had something at the bottom-left of their main 3D view that created a text output of their mouse and keyboard actions. Does anyone know how to enable that feature?
Thanks!

Comment: The actual recording is done using any of the many "Screen Recorders" out there. I prefer "CamStudio" on windows. If you use Blender on Mac or Linux you will just need to google "screen recorder <your os here>" and you should find something. Although I think most linux distributions come with one.

Comment: An excellent screen recording option for Linux is SimpleScreenRecorder. Details on installation here: http://www.maartenbaert.be/simplescreenrecorder/

Comment: You could try KeyPress OSD . It is very advanced. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LKvhqTeb9sg

Comment: The up to date version of the Screencast keys add-on can be found here:
https://github.com/nutti/Screencast-Keys/releases/

Answer (score 30):

This is an addon called [*Screencast keys*](https://github.com/nutti/Screencast-Keys). It is [no longer distributed with the official releases due to some limitations](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/19198/599), but you can install it yourself if you want:

1. [download it](https://github.com/nutti/Screencast-Keys/releases/latest) and then click *install from file* in <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>,</kbd>*> User preferences > Addons*, then navigate to where you downloaded the zip and install.
2. Enable it, then turn it on in *3D view > Properties region (*<kbd>N</kbd>*) > Screen cast keys*:

[image]

Comment: @The Minecrafter and Blenr, most of the time you don't need to use this, unless you are making a tutorial for other people. It's primarily used in video so that watchers can understand what is going on outside the screen.