# how to display some text in blender 3Dviewport?

Tags: python, blender-internal-render-engine

How to display some text in blender 3Dviewport?
like screencast addon display pressed keys?

Comment: Why do you not want to use the screencast keys addon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can draw on the 3D viewport by registering a draw handler and using the [`bgl`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_master/bgl.html) and [`blf`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_master/blf.html) modules.

Registering the draw handler is done via `bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_add()`. Just browse through the bundled Blender add-ons to get lots of examples on how this is used in practice.

Answer (score 0):

Due to some simple limitations, the screencast keys add-on was removed from blender builds, you can read about that [here](https://developer.blender.org/T51419) . It may be possible to find it somewhere in forums or on github as an addon you can install [How do I display what keys I use?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23059/how-do-i-display-what-keys-i-use), but if that is not an option, you can use some separate software. See lists like http://www.lassanamagassa.com/2014/09/7-apps-that-display-real-time-keystrokes-on-a-windows-pc-screen/, or you might want to try [this](https://github.com/wavexx/screenkey) if your are on linux.