# How to make a spiked sphere?

Tags: modeling

I know how to make it manually with cone rotation around the sphere. but maybe there's much simpler solution or addon that has that option, preferably not very high poly solution.

Also if possible I would like the spikes not to be very pointy if that makes any sense

[Here is what I kinda have in mind](https://pixabay.com/en/small-ball-rubber-balls-toy-892166/)

[image: Rubbery-looking spiked ball]

Thanks

Comment: Related answer: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50695/emit-hair-particle-from-center-of-face

Answer (score 55):

If you want to model it as a one mesh you may achieve it *beveling* the *Ico Sphere*.
[image]

Add the ***Ico Sphere*** (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>-->*Ico Sphere*) with the 3 subdivisions.
[image]

In *Edit Mode* (with *edge selection* type) select the whole mesh (<kbd>A</kbd>), press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>, then <kbd>V</kbd> to bevel the vertices only. With a cursor placed in the middle of the mesh and a *pivot center type* set to *3D Cursor* extrude selected elements and then scale them (<kbd>E</kbd>,<kbd>S</kbd>). Next change the *pivot center type* to *Individual Origins* and scale all tips with <kbd>S</kbd>.
[image]

Give the object the *Subsurf Modifier*. Select the edge loop at the bottom of the spike, click Select-->Select Similiar-->Face Angles. Then press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> to crease them.
[image]

Comment: Hey what software did you use to do the screen-caps? I like the box showing input.

Comment: @beppe9000 I use LICEcap. I highly recommend it to you. For other solutions please check out this post:: http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/963/what-is-the-process-for-creating-gifs-for-questions-and-answers

Comment: @beppe9000 - If you're referring to the screencast keys (mouse and key presses), that an add-on that comes with Blender.

Comment: Before extruding outwards, setting *Pivot Point* to *Individual Origins* rather than *3D Cursor* was what worked for me.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway and beppe9000 Blender has removed the screencast key addon (somewhere around 2.70 I think).  See [this answer](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/19201/21825) for how to get them back.

Comment: @Gliderman - Thanks.  I remember reading that it was removed.   I had forgotten.

Comment: @PaulGonet Nitpicking: you've missed the small notches around the spikes ;)

Comment: @poor Feel free to create an add-on which may create them automatically ;).

Comment: Amazing. However, I got stuck for a while with the Bevel, for which I had to tick `vertex only` in the LH panel.

Answer (score 33):

You can easily do it with Dupliverts if you don't need a single continuous mesh surface.

Model your spikes however big and rounded you want them to be as any independent mesh object; you may need to rotate them $-90º$ in the X axis so they point up towards $Y+$ axis.

Parent it to an icosphere with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and activate the option *Dupliverts* in the *Properties Window > Object > Duplication > Verts* also activate *Rotation*.

Adjust the subdivision non destructively with a *Subdivide modifier* and then control the scale of the spikes.

You can still adjust the spikes independently by editing the original spike object.

[image: Spiked Sphere]

Comment: Ok i followed it, its kinda fast to me all is fine until i check the rotation checkbox then all spikes goes randomly different directions

Comment: You have to modify the cone in edit mode to make it match the expected rotation so all spikes point outwards. For me rotation in edit mode -90º in the X axis did it fine. Make sure you apply the ration and scale to the cone

Comment: Thanks i think i got it. Just need to practice. Thank you for your time

Oh. how can i make it as solid object? if i delete the cone inside the sphere it deletes all the spikes

Comment: You can use the Operator "Make Duplicates Real" search for it in the spacebar menu or use Shift + Ctrl + A

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the Poke tool.  Start with an icosphere, go into edit mode, select all, then use Alt-P.  In the Tools panel on the left, at the bottom, you can adjust how much they stick in or out, or use F6 to bring up its options.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0rXDVF_PijA