# How to rotate the object based on the vertex of another object?

Tags: modeling

Do you see the selected vertex, how do move the red circled object to the selected vertex as well as to rotate the object based on the vertex? rotation?[image]

(This question is different from other questions as I am asking how to position the spikes based on the body's specific vertex).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a spiked sphere?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56535/how-to-make-a-spiked-sphere)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use snapping to achieve this task.

The settings of snapping:

1. Snap to vertex
2. Target - Center
3. Align rotation is enabled.

[image]

And move object with holding <kbd>CTRL</kbd>:

[image]

PS set center of the cone object in bottom of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can snap the cursor to the selected vertex by selecting the vertex and then press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> select "cursor to selected" from the menu.

Now you need to change the pivot point to 3d-cursor from the pivot point menu [image]

This will allow you to rotate object around the 3d-cursor.