# Low-Poly Mesh-Based Fur

Tags: modeling, mesh, topology

I've been wondering how artists make low-poly 3D models look like they have hair or fur.

Recently I stumbled across this [animated Corgi model on Sketchfab](https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/corgi-animated-132e3bb7e52f47c89bba65bbb5978e4b), and it looks like the artist made some spikes that stick out of the model to make the corgi look fuzzier and messier:

[image: Spikes labeled on the Corgi model]

These fur spikes overlap the model and curl at random angles, but somehow the artist kept the topology pristine: The spikes and surrounding mesh are still mostly quads, and all the quads are mostly square.

**How could I replicate these fur spikes and still keep a nice topology?**

I tried to replicate a single spike with the "Grab" sculpting tool by pulling a vertex hard to the right:
[image]
[image]

However, the quads on this spike have become highly distorted, and the spike looks jagged and flat.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56535/how-to-make-a-spiked-sphere

Comment: Thanks for the link! I am aware of this technique for creating spikes, but it makes two assumptions that I wish not to make for the particular application of low-poly hair and fur: (1) The spikes protrude from a single vertex. (2)  Creating the spikes introduces new hexagons, and I'm hoping to stick with a minimal amount of polygons that are only triangles and quads. That was my fault for not clarifying; let me edit the question